# Rails - include and require methods over the modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, libraries

Prawn::Document::Snapshot is a module in the prawn library, so we can include this in our modules. But Prawn::Document::BoundingBox is not a module and it is a class, so how am i suppose to use(include) it in my module? And is inheritance the only way to use that class?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem... 
I dont have to include module or inherit class for my problem.
just introduced an variable along with the Prawn generate method and passed that varibale along the methods whose definition is in the module...